# How to fix Three.js Cube thin wireframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

**The problem**: The Three.js 3d cube I created has a wireframe or outline mode attribute enabled. It works correctly on desktop/tablet but when constrained down to mobile, it becomes extremely thin and unusable. I would like to stop this from happening and keep the same desktop/tablet wireframe weight but for mobile as well.

**Examples:** Here are a list of screen shots demonstrating the behavior.

- desktop (constrained to mimic iPhone 6 size in chrome browser) -

[image]

- mobile (actual iPhone 6 size in ios chrome browser) -

[image]

**Here is my current code:**

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75,     window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//makes the site responsive
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  var width = window.innerWidth; 
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:     0x00ff00, wireframe: true } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );

  cube.rotation.x += 0.025;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.025;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();
```

```css
html,body { 

  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

}
canvas { 

  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;

}
h1 {

  font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#textthing {

  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  color: #00FF00;
  /**height: 90%;**/
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;

}
```

```html
   
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro'     rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300'     rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
        

<div id="textthing">
  <h1>weeflix LLC</h1>
  <!--<h2>Coming soon.</h2>-->
  <p>Jake Schnieder  ||  Thomas Bisnitsz</p>
</div>
        
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line to the your `<head>` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

[See this MDN article for what setting the `viewport` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: alright, seems to have done the trick. I am a complete newb as you can tell. Thanks man!